# Java desktop application - which technology?

Tags: java, desktop

I have a requirement to implement a Java desktop application!

Which framework would you recommend: SWT, Swing, Java FX or some other?

I have a requirement the app should work on Windows (x86 and x64), Linux (x86 and x64) and OSX.

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Jurica Krizanic

Comment: I'd recommend using Swing in an IDE that supports design view (Such as NetBeans) if you're totally new to it so you can study the generated code and learn from it.

Comment: @MrLore that's probably not a good reason to use form editors, most generated code is bloated to one extent or another (I use form editors all the time btw). To properly learn Swing, it's best to hand code as much as you can to start with and use the form editors as you become more experienced (I started using form editors originally to cut out designs and ideas quickly and hand coded them into production, taught me a lot about layout managers) - IMHO

Comment: If you want to experiment, then JavaFX would be an interesting place to start. If you need a API that has a wide range of support and experience then Swing and SWT are probably better suited to your needs

Comment: Hasn't Swing's further development been stopped? Anyone has experience with JavaFX on all mentioned operating systems?

Comment: JavaFX, SilverLight, Adobe Flex and all software behind the "rich internet applications (RIA)" wave seem to have been surpassed by HTML5.. RIA's by the way all require a browser plugin to work, HTML5 will work without it so it has a bigger chance to win against RIA applications

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SWT is proprietary to Eclipse.  If that runs on all platforms, and you know it well, then I guess it'd be fine.

Swing is built into JDK, so it's as portable as the JVM it runs on.

I don't believe JavaFX has caught on, but I don't do much desktop development.

I'd vote for Swing first, followed by JavaFX, then SWT.

Comment: You'll learn to love Swing, we all do eventually :)

Comment: I just had my first contact with Swing embeded in NetBeans and I think it is going to be quite easy to learn!

Comment: JavaFX is best for making desktop applications. It also support HTML5 and many other feature than swing and SWT.

Comment: I'm not aware that it's winning in the marketplace, any more than Silverlight is.  Please correct me with some facts if that's wrong.